# Como usar boost::function com função com número de parâmetros variável?

Tags: c++, funções

Em uma biblioteca que uso, uma função `Z` espera um ponteiro para função com a seguinte assinatura: `typedef void (*func)(double, ...)`. 
Eu quero escrever uma classe de tal modo que possa passar um objeto desta classe como parâmetro para `Z`.

Eu saberia usar `boost.function` se `func` não tivesse o número de parâmetros variados.

Procurei na internet, mas não achei um referência específica para este caso. Alguém sabe como usar `boost.function` neste caso, ou tem alguma referência que possa me ajudar?

Grato,
   Rodrigo

Comment: Se você que manja muito de C++ não sabe, como nós saberemos? :D Espero que alguém consiga te ajudar e espero ver você ajudando um pouco por aqui também.

Comment: De onde vc me conhece para achar que eu manjo muito de C++?

Comment: Da cppbrasil ;)

Comment: Então vc deveria saber q eu não manjo muito de C++. Talvez por isso vc não me veja ajudando muito.

Comment: [Acho que achei o que você precisa](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html)

Comment: Obrigado Lucas!